# How to store logging statements(ex: console.log("some statements")) of Javascript in seprate file in PlayFramewrok application?

Tags: eclipse, playframework-2.0, vs-web-application-project

I have one Activator project, the controllers which i have written for that i am able to log into seprate file. Now i have some JS file which contains some logging statments too which i want to store in same log file.

**Application.java sample**

```
public static Result index() throws Exception {
    Logger.of(LoggerConstants.OTNlogger).debug(LoggerConstants.methodEntry);
    // CommonUtils.createDBConnection();

    if (isSessionExist()) {
        Logger.of(LoggerConstants.OTNlogger).debug(
                LoggerConstants.returnObj + LoggerConstants.loggerSpace);
        Logger.of(LoggerConstants.OTNlogger).debug(
                LoggerConstants.methodExit);
        return ok(tool.render());
    } else {
        Logger.of(LoggerConstants.OTNlogger).debug(LoggerConstants.methodExit);
        return badRequest(main.render());
    }
}
```

**Logger.xml**

```
<configuration debug="true">

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder 
        by default -->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logFile.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

        <!-- keep 1 days' worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>5</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%caller{2}  : %r]   %p  %logger{0} - %msg  %n</pattern>
        <!-- time, [caller level : excution time of method], level, loggerName, - message -->
    </encoder>

</appender>


<logger name="ODE" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />

</logger>

<logger name="play" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />

</logger>


<root level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />

</root>
```

**LogFile.log sample**

15:58:22.491 [Caller+0   at play.Logger$ALogger.debug(Logger.java:332)
Caller+1     at com.egnaro.utils.CommonUtils.createDBConnection(CommonUtils.java:30)
  : 81754]   DEBUG  ODE - Entered into method
15:58:22.512 [Caller+0   at play.Logger$ALogger.info(Logger.java:361)
Caller+1     at com.egnaro.utils.CommonUtils.createDBConnection(CommonUtils.java:33)
  : 81775]   INFO  ODE - Morphia Object Intilizing
15:58:22.927 [Caller+0   at play.Logger$ALogger.info(Logger.java:361)
Caller+1     at com.egnaro.utils.CommonUtils.createDBConnection(CommonUtils.java:46)
  : 82190]   INFO  ODE - Databse created

**sample.js**

```
function inputEditor(data, event){
    var treeView = $("#tree").data("kendoTreeView");    
    var selectedNode = treeView.select(), 
    dataItem = treeView.dataItem(selectedNode);

    //var span = $(this).find('.k-sprite').hide();
    //var span = $(this).find('.k-sprite').detach();

    $target = $(event.target);
    $target.editable(function (value, settings)
    {
        console.log(this);
        return value;
    },
    {
        submit:'ok',
        event: 'dblclick',
        cssclass: 'editableTree'
    });

    //return;
    //$(this).find('.k-sprite').append(span);
    $target.trigger('dblclick', [event]);
    //$(this).find('.k-sprite').append(span);

}
```

I want to store log for console.log() in my loggerfile. Please give step by step explanation, i'm new in playframework.

Comment: Javascript like `console.log` is executed by the browser, not the server. Play configuration can't help you here. There's certainly a javascript library out there someone that will help you log to a file.

Comment: @m-z write an answer before this question will bo closed.

Comment: I am still finding solution for it, looking for how to implement.

Comment: Pravin, @m-z answered you - console.log is called on the CLIENT side and Play has NOTHING to do with it... is that really so hard to understand difference between client/server side parts ? If you want to save the logs, you need to handle it as a common ajax request - yourself

Comment: Consider your site as a car and Play as a factory, your car doesn't need to contact to factory to check the fuel level, and vice versa, factory doesn't care that in your car "low fuel level" indicator starts to light. These are two separate things.